# Continuous Quadratic Form $\implies$ Continuous Sesquilinear Form

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a quadratic form $q:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Define its inducing sesquilinear form:
$$s:\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}: s(x,y):=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4 i^k q(x+i^ky)$$

How to prove that:
$$|q(x)|\leq\|q\|\cdot\|x\|^2\text{ for all }x\in\mathcal{H}\implies|s(x,y)|\leq\|s\|\cdot\|x\|\cdot\|y\|\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathcal{H}$$
and especially: $\|s\|=\|q\|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Parallelogram law $\|x+y\|^{2}+\|x-y\|^{2}=2\|x\|^{2}+2\|y\|^{2}$:
$$
   |s(x,y)| \le \frac{\|q\|}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}\|x+i^{n}y\|^{2}
      = \|q\|\{\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}\}.
$$
I'm going to assume that you know somehow that your definition of $s$ is sesquilinear; this is a separate issue. Then, if $x \ne 0$, $y \ne 0$, the above implies
$$
       \frac{|s(x,y)|}{\|x\|\|y\|}
               = \left|s\left(\frac{1}{\|x\|}x,\frac{1}{\|y\|}y\right)\right|
               \le 2\|q\|,
$$
which gives $|s(x,y)| \le 2\|q\|\|x\|\|y\|$ for $x\ne 0$, $y\ne 0$. The cases where $x=0$ and $y=0$ are handled by dividing by $(\|x\|+\epsilon)$ and/or $(\|y\|+\epsilon)$ instead, and letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ after clearing denominators.

It's not true in general that $|s(x,y)| \le \|q\|\|x\|\|y\|$. However, if $q$ is real, then you get this improved estimate because you can choose $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $e^{i\theta}s(x,y)$ is real, which forces
$$
         e^{i\theta}s(x,y) = s(e^{i\theta}x,y)= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}q(e^{i\theta}x+iy) \\
              = \frac{1}{4}\{ q(e^{i\theta}x+y)-q(e^{i\theta}x-y)\},
$$
which cuts the estimated bound in half.

Comment: Why does the very last equality hold for a real quadratic form?

Comment: Ah ok got it; since the sesquilinear form was adjusted to be real the imaginary terms in the sum have to vanish...

Comment: Unfortunately my example in my head cannot be made real at all. Anyway thanks alot for the great answer!

Comment: @Freeze_S : If your quadratic form cannot be made real, then the desired result may not be true. It depends on the specifics of your $q$. Second issue: Knowing only that (a) $q(x+y)+q(x-y)=2q(x)+2q(y)$ for all $x$, $y$ and (b) $|q(x)| \le C\|x\|^{2}$ for all $x$ and some $C$, you can prove that $s$ is fully sesquilinear. Without such a bound, the result that $s(\alpha x,y)=\alpha s(x,y)$ might not hold for all $\alpha$. Alternatively, if $q(x) \ge 0$ with $q(\alpha x)=|\alpha|^{2}q(x)$, then $s$ is sesquilinear.