# Spectral Measures: Integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and spectral a measure $E:\Sigma(\Omega)\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

How to define the integral for unbounded measurable functions:
$$f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}:\quad\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}E=?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a linear operator $\int_{\Omega} f\,dE$ on the domain
$$
   \mathcal{D}\left(\int_{\Omega}f\,dE\right) = 
      \left\{ x \in \mathcal{H} : \int_{\Omega}|f(t)|^{2}\,d\|E(t)x\|^{2} < \infty \right\}.
$$
The linear operator is most easily defined as the unique vector $\int_{\Omega} f\,dEx$ such that
$$
         \int_{\Omega}f(t)\,d(E(t)x,y) = \left(\int_{\Omega}f\,dEx\,,\,y\right),\;\;\; y \in \mathcal{H}.
$$
**Justification:** The measure $\mu_{x,y}(S)=(E(S)x,y)$ is a complex measure of finite total variation on $\Omega$, because $\mu_{w,w}$ is a finite positive measure for each $w \in X$, and $\mu_{x,y}$ can be written as a sum of four such measures by using the polarization identity for Hilbert space:
$$\mu_{x,y}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^{n}\mu_{x+i^{n}y,x+i^{n}y}.$$
For simple functions $f = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\chi_{S_{j}}$ where the $S_{j}$ are disjoint Borel subsets of $\Omega$,
$$
\begin{align}
    \left|\int_{\Omega} f d(E(t)x,y)\right|^{2} 
         & = \left| \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}(E(S_{j})x,y)\right|^{2} \\
         & = \left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}(E(S_{j})x,E(S_{j})y)\right|^{2} \\
         & \le \sum_{j=1}^{n}|\alpha_{j}|^{2}\|E(S_{j})x\|^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|E(S_{j})y \|^{2} \\
         & = \int_{\Omega}|f|^{2}d\|E(t)x\|^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|E(S_{j})y\|^{2} \\
         & \le \left(\int_{\Omega}|f|^{2}d\|E(t)x\|^{2}\right)\|y\|^{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for any $f \in \mathcal{D}\left(\int_{\Omega}fdE\right)$,
$$
           \left|\int_{\Omega}f(t)d(E(t)x,y)\right|\le |f|_{x}\|y\|,
$$
where $|f|_{x}=\left(\int_{\Omega}|f(t)|^{2}\,d\|E(t)x\|^{2}\right)^{1/2}$, which, by the Riesz Representation Theorem, guarantees the existence of a unique vector $\int_{\Omega}f\,dEx$ such that
$$
             \int_{\Omega}f(t)d(E(t)x,y) = \left(\int_{\Omega} fdE x\,,\,y\right),\;\;\; y \in \mathcal{H}.
$$
**Norm Identities:** It is easy to check that the domain of $\int_{\Omega}fdE$ is a linear subspace and $\int_{\Omega}fdE$ is linear on its domain. If $f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\chi_{S_{j}}(t)$ where the $S_{j}$ are disjoint Borel sets, then uniqueness of the Riesz Representation guarantees
$$
                        \int_{\Omega} f dEx = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}E(S_{j})x.
$$
Therefore, for a simple function $f$,
$$
     \left\|\int_{\Omega}f\,dEx\right\|^{2} = \int_{\Omega}|f(t)|^{2}d\|E(t)x\|^{2}.
$$
The Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem shows that the above equality continues to hold for all $x \in \mathcal{D}\left(\int_{\Omega}fdE\right)$, for any bounded or unbounded Borel function $f$.

**Operator Properties:** It should be noted that if the Borel function $f$ is uniformly bounded by $M$, then $\int_{\Omega}fdE$ is a bounded linear operator whose operator norm is bounded by $M$.

For a general Borel function $f$, the domain of $\int_{\Omega}fdE$ is invariant under $E(S)$ because
$$
        \int_{\Omega}|f(t)|^{2}d\|E(t)E(S)x\|^{2}=\int_{S}|f(t)|^{2}\,d\|E(t)x\|^{2}
          \le \int_{\Omega}|f(t)|^{2}d\|E(t)x\|^{2}.
$$
Let $S_{N}=\{ t\in\Omega :|f(t)| \le N\}$. The range of $E(S_{N})$ is in the domain of $\int_{\Omega}f\,dE$ for any positive integer $N$. Furthermore, $x = \lim_{N}E(S_{N})x$ for all $x$ because $\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}S_{N}=\Omega$. Therefore, **the domain of $\int_{\Omega}f\,dE$ is dense**, even for an unbounded Borel function $f$.

Next it is shown that $\int_{\Omega}f\,dE$ **is closed.** To this end, suppose that $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathcal{D}(\int_{\Omega}fdE)$ converges to some $x$, and suppose that $\int_{\Omega}fdEx_{n}$ converges to some $y$. Let $S_{N}=\{ t\in\Omega : |f(t)| \le N\}$. Then $(\int_{\Omega}fdE)E(S_{N})$ is a bounded linear operator, which gives
$$
\begin{align}
  \int_{\Omega}fdE\cdot E(S_{N})x
     & = \lim_{n}\int_{\Omega}fdE\cdot E(S_{N})x_{n} \\
     & = \lim_{n}E(S_{N})\int_{\Omega}fdE x_{n} \\
     & = E(S_{N})y.
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
          \int_{S_{N}}|f(t)|^{2}d\|E(t)x\|^{2} = \|E(S_{N})y\|^{2} \le \|y\|^{2}.
$$
Because this holds for all $N \ge 1$, it follows that $x \in \mathcal{D}(\int_{\Omega}fdE)$ and the previous identity gives
$$
                      E(S_{N})\left(\int_{\Omega}fdE x - y\right) = 0,\;\;\; N \ge 1 \\
                         \implies \int_{\Omega}fdE x  = y.
$$
Therefore, $\int_{\Omega}f dE$ is a **closed densely-defined** operator for a complex unbounded Borel function $f$.

It's not hard to show that the following **adjoint equation** holds:
$$
                 \left(\int_{\Omega} fdE\right)^{\star} = \int_{\Omega}\overline{f}dE.
$$

Comment: Hey that seems kind of similar to your other answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/941481/79762

Comment: Well using the polarization identity together with Riesz' representation might give not the best estimates as observed in the other thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/924505/79762

Comment: I'll leave it to you to show $|\int_{\Omega}fd(E(t)x,y)|^{2}\le \int_{\Omega}|f|^{2}d(E(t)x,x)\|y\|^{2}$. Because all of the measures $\mu_{x,y}(S)=(E(S)x,y)$ are finite, you can also do interesting things with Radon-Nikodym once you realize that $\mu_{x,y} << \mu_{x,x}$ for all $y$, which follows from Cauchy-Schwarz. There are lots of options here.

Comment: @Freeze_S : For the first inequality, start with simple functions.

Comment: @Freeze_S : I decided it might be generally useful to cover this topic in some depth. So I've added a lot of detail for you.

Comment: That is very kind! Thanks for this!!! (By the way I already voted up hope you will get more votes...)

Comment: Also give me some time to go through it

Comment: @Freeze_S : I just finished a full round of edits to clean up loose ends. I'll leave it alone now.